# How can I get IF-INDEX-MATCH to compare 2 columns to other 2 columns in MS excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: excel image here]

What I want to do:

`Set 1:` Columns A & B

`Set 2:` Columns E & F

`Set 3:` Columns I & J

If A13 **AND** B13 have a match in column E and F (and in column I and J if I get the set 1 vs set 2 correctly), respectively, I want to get the value of the match at (I'm testing for) column G (which is G12 for this example).

All values in A & B are taken in pairs. Basically, this is pair vs pair vs pair matching to get a corresponding value in Column G corresponding to the A & B position.

What I am trying to do is that if values in column A & B match with E & F and I & J. Then I want to get the values of column C, G, and K in three separate columns. This will only work if `Set 1 = Set 2 = Set 3`.

I am getting a `#VALUE!` with my formula. I don't know why the index-match matches A13 and B13 to E13 and D13.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I'm still a little unclear on how exactly you mean A13 and B13 match E and F. Which single value is to match within which range?

Comment: Your formula is an array type formula.  You will need to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner! That solved it! 

I apologize for the confusion @jatuttle0. I am not well-versed in systematically constructing my thoughts in words.

Comment: @jfo, welcome to Super User, and glad you got your problem solved.  Other users might see the question and come to help, or have a similar problem and come looking for a solution.  The answer is hidden in comments, which aren't necessarily permanent.  It would be helpful to others if you post your own answer (and in 2 days, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark and that will indicate that the problem is solved).  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was "to confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter." as Scott Craner suggested.